# How can I remove the message from jquery for last checkbox chosen

Tags: jquery

Im learning quickly but having trouble removing the text "nothing showing" from code below which I used elsewhere on my site and it works good.

In this instance I dont need "nothing showing" bit, just the value of the last checked checkbox which it gets fine. How can I remove "nothing showing" from my code as not needed at all -

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {  
var result = $('input:checked').length==0?"nothing showing":$(this).val();
alert(result);
```

Tried this but not working

```
var result = $('input:checked').length:$(this).val();
```

Comment: try $('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked") instead of $('input:checked').length==0

Comment: ok do u mean like var result = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked"):$(this).val();

Comment: No i means  var result = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked") ? "nothing showing":$(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


 jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {  

  var target = jQuery(this);

  if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true){
      var result = jQuery(this).val();
      alert(result);
  }
 

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" id="xyz" value="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox">
```